# I want to have type text/javascript, but it fails with 'image/gif'

Tags: javascript, mime-types

How can I change from image/gif to text/javascript (or application/javascript)?

FTP -> edit code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var vglnk = {key: '61641f74b8eb29a4321bb1f55d6030c5'}; //pseudo key
    (function(d, t) {
        var s = d.createElement(t);
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = '//cdn.viglink.com/api/vglnk.js';
        var r = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(s, r);
    }(document, 'script'));
</script>
```

browser -> view js console:
`Refused to execute script from 'https://api.viglink.com/api/sync.js?key=61641f74b8eb29a4321bb1f55d6030c5' because its MIME type ('image/gif') is not executable. viewtopic.php:1`
​

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your key is incorrect. I tried visiting `https://api.viglink.com/api/sync.js?key=abcd`, it returns GIF. This might be their prevention system.

However, when I get a proper key and requested with `https://api.viglink.com/api/sync.js?key=properKeyThatIGot` (replace `properKeyThatIGot` with your key), I get the JavaScript file as expected.

Comment: Can you explain to me? pseudo key is e.g.
line #2: `key: '61641f74b8eb29a4321bb1f55d6030c5'};`
Of course I have standard key / properKeyThatIGot.

Comment: @Dani This is my guess: when you request `//cdn.viglink.com/api/vglnk.js`, it also requests other resources as well (`api.viglink.com/api/sync.js` in this case). They have a check that if the key is correct, it returns the correct JS file (`sync.js`) back. If not, they just return random things (GIF in this case) to protect their system.

If I were them, I would return either 400/401/403 instead of a GIF to make the requester understand what's wrong.