# Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('image/gif') is not executable

Tags: javascript

I have added this code to my website (before the closing body):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var vglnk = {key: '123456789'};
    (function(d, t) {
        var s = d.createElement(t);
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = '//cdn.viglink.com/api/vglnk.js';
        var r = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(s, r);
    }(document, 'script'));
</script>
```

(The key above is just a dummy key. In my production environment I have used the correct key.)

However, in Chrome's developer console I get the following error:

```
www.mywebsite.com/:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://api.viglink.com/api/sync.js?key=123456789' because its MIME type ('image/gif') is not executable.
```

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm going to guess that `cdn.viglink.com/api/vglnk.js` has an incorrect MIME type associated with it, but unfortunately the client-side code you've posted won't help us figure out why that's happening.

Comment: Yep, just did a quick HTTP header check and that file mime type is set as "gif". Nothing you can do about it in your end. You'll have to notify the owners about their server misconfiguration

Comment: Thank you so much! That's impressive - this must affect Viglink.com's entire business for all newer Chrome Versions I assume.

Comment: I don’t see where you sending vglnk key in request.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your key is correct?

The `gif` response could be how viglink is handling invalid requests - if the key is not valid, return a `gif`. Directly visit `https://api.viglink.com/api/sync.js?key=123` in your browser and it returns GIF.

However, I tested it with a valid key:

`https://api.viglink.com/api/sync.js?key=<valid-key>`

and it returned the `sync.js` javascript file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a **<script>** element that is trying to load some external JavaScript.

**The URL you have given - it possibly points to a GIF file and not a JavaScript program.**

The server is correctly reporting that it is GIF so the browser is aborting with that error message instead of trying to execute the JSON as JavaScript (which would throw an error).

try this

```
  <script type="image/gif">
```

*Now the browser knows it isn't trying to load JavaScript, so it ignores the script element entirely*

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69062364/2534980), it seems that once you put the right key in the URL you'll get a valid Javascript file.